# Stuck after Kernel Panic after Timout while waiting for device on initramfs

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs

I encounter the screen shown below independed of starting ubuntu normal or in recovery mode. After the Kernel Panic I can't make any input as suggested by the many similar threads.

[image: Output on boot]

In the advanced ubuntu options I can choose between the following (all leading to the same result) or grub mode.

[image: Boot options]

I am not aware of me doing any update or similar and now I am somehow lost here.

**UPDATE 1**

I managed to mount the LUKS encrypted partition /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root with a live usb -> the exact location what the initramfs is looking for. But what now? It seems the initramfs is looking for this /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root at some wrong place.

Comment: Was the machine cleanly shutdown during the last session when it worked normally? If it wasn't (*one time where I have had a kernel panic on boot*) I tend to not try and boot my system normally, but boot a *live* system on thumb-drive & perform file-system checks (`fsck`) of my disk partition(s).. If any problems are detected, they'll be fixed (*providing I used a command appropriate for my chosen file-system*) and I expect normal operation on next boot. Other alternatives are because I made a change in the last working session, but I usually have a clue as to what I did; did you do anything?

Comment: I recently build some software using cmake and due to an error of some missing stddef.h which were looked up in a parent folder I copied some folders (from .../x to .../linux/x) somewhere in the /usr directories. But I thought I have done a reboot since then. And everything worked out. But this could be the cause.

Comment: If the various kernel options you have available in grub (*and shown on your provided screenshot*) do not work, given the detail in your last comment (*which is vague*) I'd suggest start a restore of data in the directories where you copied data into, from your backups. For us to provide help, we need specifics & your details (*mostly in comment*) are too vague for me (*and likely others*) to provide specific help. Given it appears to be a desktop system (*you didn't specify*) I'd consider a non-destructive re-install if backups are a problem & you don't get other suggestions

Comment: @guiverc what info would you need? Also, please see my update.